# The least sum of a combination of three different columns, where numbers are in different rows

Tags: algorithm, sum, time-complexity

The part of solution for one of my algorithm tasks requires to find efficiently the least sum of three numbers, where each are in separate columns and rows. Let's take this for example:

```
2 6 5
1 3 2
2 3 4
5 2 2
0 1 0
```

The least sum is 1 (1st column,2nd row) + 2 (2nd column, 4th row) + 0 (3rd column,5th row) = 3
Of course it can be made in O(n^3), but it's too much when we deal with 3*10^5 rows.

Kind regards and thank you in advance for any helpful answer

Comment: Find the least 3 numbers of each columns. That least sum is definitely exists within this set of 9 numbers.

Comment: @ytlu If you flesh that out just a little, that's a nice answer :)

Comment: @ytlu I came out with that solution (3! permutations) way before, but asked because it didn't comply with task solution, but apparently my strategy was just bad, but the part given in the question was correct. Thank you for your time and making me sure about that approach :)

Comment: From your sample data, I expect many different conbinations that will give the same least sum. But how will you handle these multifold degeneracy is an issue beyoud the discussion here. Anyway, wish you be well with your project.